# Baire Theorem and examples

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a conceptual question, about Baire theorem and a particular application, why a metric space of a single point, does not violate Baire's theorem?

Comment: What's the precise statement of Baire's theorem you have in mind, and what part of it are you unsure about in this case?

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the formulation of Baire's theorem that talks about intersection of countably many dense open sets, then the only dense and open subset of $X = \{ \textrm{pt} \}$ is $X$ itself and an arbitrary intersection of $X$'s result in $X$ and so it is dense (and even open!).

If you consider the formulation of Baire's theorem that talks about the space not being a union of countably-many nowhere-dense sets, note that $X$ is not nowhere dense as $\overline{X}^{\circ} = X^{\circ} = X$ since $X$ is both open and closed.